# AWS copilot is failing to create resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Trying to follow this tutorial for AWS copilot but terminal is showing failed output.
Unclear what's happening so here's some output + permissions policy.

Here's my IAM permissions policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*",
                "ssm:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "ecr:*",
                "sts:*",
                "tag:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:PutParameter",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:xxxxxx61741:parameter/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
Use existing application: No
Application name: demo
Workload type: Load Balanced Web Service
Service name: api
Dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
no EXPOSE statements in Dockerfile ./Dockerfile
Port: 
Ok great, we'll set up a Load Balanced Web Service named api in application demo listening on port 80.

✔ Created the infrastructure to manage services and jobs under application demo.

✔ Wrote the manifest for service api at ../api/manifest.yml
Your manifest contains configurations like your container size and port (:80).

✔ Created ECR repositories for service api.

All right, you're all set for local development.
Deploy: Yes

✘ Failed to create the infrastructure for the test environment.
- Virtual private cloud on 2 availability zones to hold your services and jobs     [Complete]
  - Internet gateway to connect the network to the internet                        [Failed]
  Resource creation cancelled                                                               
  - Public subnets for internet facing services and jobs                           [Failed]
  Resource creation cancelled                                                               
  - Private subnets for services and jobs that can't be reached from the internet  [Failed]
  Resource creation cancelled                                                               
  - Routing tables for services and jobs to talk with each other                   [Complete]
- ECS Cluster to hold your services and jobs                                       [Complete]
✘ wait until stack demo-test create is complete: ResourceNotReady: failed waiting for successful resource state
```

Any idea what's going on?
Is this a permissions error?
How can I debug this?

Comment: Hi @Last_Node_Standing, thanks so much for trying out Copilot! Sorry you're blocked on this. There's a [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/1345#issue-689021141) on our repository that details a working minimal set of permissions for running `copilot init`. We're super happy to answer questions and typically a lot more responsive over there, as we don't have much visibility into SO.